# Extract changes from Wikipedia/Wikimedia revision pages

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I have a simple query regarding the Wikimedia/Wikipedia API.

I have to fetch the changes made from a list of "revids". I am able to fetch the XML content for a batch of "revids", but I failed to extract only the changed text.

Does API provide any way to extract only the changed sentences? If not any external script/module that can do this job?

**Query to fetch the revision details:** [https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info|revisions&rvprop=user|userid|ids|tags|comment|content&format=jsonfm&revids=1228415](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info%7Crevisions&rvprop=user%7Cuserid%7Cids%7Ctags%7Ccomment%7Ccontent&format=jsonfm&revids=1228415)

I would appreciate any suggestions/solutions that could solve this issue!

(Currently, I am using the Wikitools python module to make the queries)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the diff between the old and new text with [`action=compare`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=compare&format=json&fromrev=1228415&torelative=prev), but it segments text by wikitext lines, not sentences, isn't meant to be machine-readable, and is generally not that helpful. Since you are using Python, the client-side library [deltas](https://pythonhosted.org/deltas/) will probably work better for you.

Comment: To provide some context, I am trying to use the same method as used by the authors of [Wikipedia-Detox](https://github.com/ewulczyn/wiki-detox) publication to extract sentences added in a particular revision of a page. They must have deployed a similar method to extract the changes from Talk pages. I could not figure out how they achieved it, did they use the same lib as mentioned above?

Comment: Looks like they have their own [diff logic](https://github.com/ewulczyn/wiki-detox/blob/master/src/data_generation/diff_utils.py)? The easiest way is to just ask them though. Also there is a [research mailing list](https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/wiki-research-l) for these kinds of questions.

Comment: I looked at that file, but could not figure out the high-level information like input & output formats. Apparently, I have emailed the author regarding this query but haven't received a reply yet. I was hoping to get a generic solution meanwhile. I will try to move the discussion on the mailing list to reach a wide audience.